Tableau percentage calculation is giving error for can't mis aggregate and non aggregate. Any suggestions on a fix?
I am still learning tableau. I am trying to create a dual axis line graph where I have the retention percentage of the control group vs non group. I am trying to create a calculation for retention percentage for both. But I am getting the "can't mis aggregate and non aggregate" error. I understand why but I have no idea how to fix it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Example of my calculation is below
IF [CONTROL_GROUP] = 'Yes' then COUNTD([MEMBER_ID]) / TOTAL(COUNTD([MEMBER_ID])) end

countd() yields a single a number, so there's nothing to aggregate. After all, what would total() of a single number be? But taking one step back: even if that did work, you'd be calculating the value 1 because the numerator and denominator are the same value. So: what is this function supposed to be calculating?

Your original formula:
IF [CONTROL_GROUP] = 'Yes' THEN COUNTD([MEMBER_ID]) / TOTAL(COUNTD([MEMBER_ID])) END


[CONTROL_GROUP] = 'Yes' is evaluated at the row level (non-aggregated)
COUNTD([MEMBER_ID]) and TOTAL(COUNTD([MEMBER_ID])) are aggregate functions.

Tableau cam't mix aggregate and non-aggregate within the same IF expression.
To fix the error:
As you are trying to calculate retention status, I'm assuming there's a field called [Retained] (or similar) to indicate retention status. The corrected formula would be:
COUNTD(
  IF [CONTROL_GROUP] = 'Yes' AND [Retained] = 'Yes' THEN [MEMBER_ID] END
) / COUNTD(
  IF [CONTROL_GROUP] = 'Yes' THEN [MEMBER_ID] END
)


Numerator: The number of distinct MEMBER_IDs in the control group who are retained.
Denominator: Total number of distinct MEMBER_IDs in the control group.

By wrapping the IF statements within COUNTD(), calculations are performed at aggregate level.
Create a second similar calculation for [CONTROL_GROUP] = 'No' to create the dual axis line graph.
